# What's wrong with this app layout?

Tags: c++, layout, header-files

Current program layout. The left operand includes the right one.

```
source.cpp
    app.hpp // Also includes SFML libraries with sf namespace
        game.hpp
            ball.hpp
            brick.hpp
            plate.hpp
```

The implementation of ball class (ball.cpp) throws a lot of errors "*sf does not name a type*".

source.cpp

```
#include "app.hpp"
int main () {
    App app(640, 480, "Arkanoid");
    while (app.getWindow()->isOpen()) app.run();
    return 0; }
```

app.hpp

```
#ifndef ArkanoidApp
#define ArkanoidApp
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "game.hpp"
// code
#endif
```

game.hpp

```
#ifndef ArkanoidGame
#define ArkanoidGame
#include "ball.hpp"
#include "brick.hpp"
#include "paddle.hpp"
// code
#endif
```

ball.hpp

```
#ifndef ArkanoidBall
#define ArkanoidBall
class Ball
{
    public:
             Ball(void);
        void draw(void);
    public: // Setters & getters
    private: // Variables
        sf::CircleShape circle; // sf is not a class type
        sf::Vector2i position;  // sf is not a class type
        sf::Vector2f direction; // sf is not a class type
    private: // Constants
        int RADIUS   = 8;
        int VELOCITY = 6;
};
#endif
```

Comment: The error is basically telling you `sf` isn't a class.  According to your code comment, it's a namespace.

Comment: I use it like this when I declare a variable: `sf::RenderWindow window;`

Comment: I assume that you mean that there is a *compilation error* rather than runtime exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Yes, compilation errors.

Comment: It makes no sense to discuss errors in code without being able to look at the code.

Comment: I'll add it in few seconds. I tried to make post as minimal as possible.

Comment: @n.m Posted the codethe code!

Comment: Ball.hpp doesn't know what `sf` is because you did not #include any header that could possibly define it.

Comment: @n.m Ah, I guess it's just a terrible program design... If I include SFML libraries to the ball.hpp, the compiler complains of undefined reference to the constructor of Game class. I guess I'll just need to read some books on the related topic and look at some source codes of little games made by experienced programmers. Thanks for the time you spent.

Comment: If you don't understand a compiler message, it's not a design issue, it's knowing your tools issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your `app.hpp` includes the sf, of course `ball.cpp` wouldn't know about it and throw an error, you would need to include the sf inside the `ball.cpp` as well.

To avoid multiple definitions use `#pragma once` in your header files.

Other then that it's unclear what and why are you trying to do, if you get to a point where files should include each other it's not a very good design and should be avoided, best design is a tree one.

**edit:**

For now you can just include the library in every header that requires it (app, ball...).
But you may try something more complicated like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). And since it's a  graphics library you can create a `View` and write all your view management there, like opening the window drawing the model etc..

What you do in MVC is a complete separation between model(game, ball) and the view, since you can display the model in different ways, one in 2D and another in 3D, each may use different library and view but the model is still the same.

There are a lot of designs and no correct one, as long as it easy to understand and maintain/add features it's a good design.

Comment: Every header file of mine uses include guards. Where can I learn good program design?

Comment: Again very general question, google c++ design book.

Comment: Yes, I included the SFML library everywhere it was needed and now the program works!